# Passing parameters to a javascript function called through 'onclick' attribute

Tags: javascript, jsf

I need to create links on webpage which call a javascript function with different parameters on being triggered by `onclick` event. Thus function needs to be passed a paramter.

In my code as shown below, I am passing a parameter to `wr()` function when calling from `onclick` within `commandLink`. Howver the code doesnt successfully execute if I pass `i` as parameter to `wr()` function within `onclick`, but is successful if I pass a constant ie, `wr(4)`. How can I successfully pass a variable parameter to this javascript function ?

```
            <h:form>
                <ui:repeat value="#{bean.list}" var="i">
                    <p:commandLink onclick="wr(i)" value="#{i}" /><br/>
                </ui:repeat>
            </h:form>

            <p id="e">fd</p>

            <script type="text/javascript" >
                function wr(i){
                    document.getElementById("e").innerHTML="this is "+i+ " !";
                }
            </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't your markup for the onclick attribute evaluate the variable 'i' using #{i} instead of just passing 'i'?

So it should be:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.list}" var="i">
  <p:commandLink onclick="wr(#{i})" value="'#{i}'" /><br/>
</ui:repeat>
```

Have you used something like [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see what 'i' is evaluting too inside of your JS function?

**Edit:** Updated the markup above to enclose the #{i} expression in single '' quotes

Comment: yes I saw thorugh firebug that the expression was ultimately evaluating to something like `wr(one)` with `onclick="wr(#{i})"`, which should be actually `wr('one')` with `onclick="wr('#{i}')`

Comment: Ok great - I updated my answer to account for wrapping the expression in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the reference of the element using `this`. It is more flexible than just passing hard parameters.

eg: `...onclick="wr(this)"...`

and then

```
function wr(elm){
  document.getElementById("e").innerHTML="this is "+ elm.value + " !";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this:

```xml
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.list}" var="i">
   <p:commandLink onclick="wr('#{i}')" /><br/>
</ui:repeat>
```